# How would I set a timeframe from an hour of today to an hour of tomorrow in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to compare two times using UTC hours. In Central Time, the hours are 8-20, which would translate to 13(today)-1(tomorrow). Below is the conditional I currently have. What can I do to make it "open" from 13 to 1 on two different days?

On another note: is it bad practice to use .getUTCHours() after new Date()? Or even just in general, as in declaring something using a function().function()?

```js
const hour = new Date().getUTCHours();
let display;

if (hour >= 13 && hour < 1) {
    display = "open";
} else {
    display = "closed";
}
```

Thanks so much!

**EDIT**: Realized OR-ing instead of the AND worked the same and required much less work.

Comment: Are you aware of the `getDay()` function on the Date object?

Comment: (and no there's no reason you can't chain functions; just keep an eye on readability)

Comment: Wasn't aware of the getDay()! I'll look into that and see if that works for me! And @jabaa it's just that I was comparing a later hour to an earlier hour of the same day haha

Comment: Wouldn't `if (hour >= 13 || hour < 1) {` solve your problem?

Comment: Ahh I suppose so! I was so caught up in figuring out how to do this date thing I didn't even think about Or... Thank you and both you guys for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace

```
if (hour >= 13 && hour < 1) {
```

with

```
if (hour >= 13 || hour < 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Wouldn't `if (hour >= 13 || hour < 1) {` solve your problem?*

I guess that does not factor in today/tomorrow piece from the question :)

I suggest to use [dayjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs) lib for that.

```
const now = dayjs();
const today_13h = now.hour(13);
const tomorrow_1h = now.add(1, 'd').hour(1);
if (now.isBetween(today_13h, tomorrow_1h)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example where _"tomorrow"_ would change the result? How could `if (hour >= 13 || hour < 1) {` return a different result than `if (now.isBetween(today_13h, tomorrow_1h)) {`?

Comment: Current time 00:30? It matches `hour < 1`,  but that's today, not tomorrow?

Comment: How could the current time ever be tomorrow < 1? How can today be tomorrow? With this explanation this code `if (now.isBetween(today_13h, tomorrow_1h)) {` doesn't make any sense. It's the same as `if (now.isAfter(today_13h)) {`.

Comment: If you only deal with current time, yes; but if you do same check for an arbitrary time (say, some sort of schedule app, where user can enter any time ;)... anyway, my point is `dayjs` is a good lib to have in mind for any tricky date/ time manipulations.